# How to reorder series in multivariable barchart in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I used this code to make a barchart in ggplot with location as an x-axis and direction as a series:

```
ggplot(bp, aes(location, avg, fill=direction)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

I get this as my figure:
[image]

However, I want the order of the bars within the series to be W on the left and E on the right. I know there is a reorder function within ggplot but can't figure out how to make it work for 1. a fill series rather than the x-axis values and 2. a categorical variable sorted in a specific order rather than a number sorted by increasing or decreasing.

```
bp <- data.frame(
  avg = c(
    0.290295409135636, 0.662679922241013, 0.0157451189744425, 0.458147570483339,
    0.281818457065378, 0.821172852462277, 0.260305525502705, 0.0588071699123448,
    0.208385246183277
  ),
  location = rep(c("Narraguagus", "Bluehill", "Jericho"), 3),
  direction = rep(c("R", "W", "E"), each = 3L)
)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: added dput to the original question

Comment: I don't understand the _a fill series rather than the x-axis values_ part. What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: I meant that I want to change the order of the colored direction bars (E,R,W), not the order of the groups of location bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order within fill argument we could use `fct_relevel` from `forcats` package, as ggplot will order by alphabet:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(df, aes(location, avg, fill=fct_relevel(direction, "W", "R", "E"))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  labs(fill = "direction")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For your second question, you could set the levels in reverse order:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bp %>% 
  mutate(direction = factor(direction, levels = sort(unique(.data$direction), decreasing = TRUE))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(location, avg, fill = direction)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

This returns
[image]

Comment: Note to OP based on their question (since it sounds like they want a solution that generalizes beyond reverse order): coders automate creating factor levels when plotting so the levels adjust as values change, but if you want a specific order for a different purpose, you can always hard code it when you make the factor. See 15.2 of Hadley's book: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html. In the above answer, you would supply the levels you prefer, in order, in the `levels` argument in the `mutate` line.